# A HREF Link does not work for constantly changing inner span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Take a look at this JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8wbxc2a3/1/

Basically I am applying a rainbow effect to some text.
I also want to be able to link this text to another webpage.
However, clicking on the link does not work.
The JSFiddle does an alert to demonstrate my point.

If we increase the `animateInterval` from `125` to say `500`, it will begin working again. What is the issue here exactly and how can we fix it so linking works all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the `z-index` on the `.test` element, it will work

```
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;            /*  Edge/IE wanted this too for it to work  */
}
.test {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wbxc2a3/3/)